# why destructor for instance not called while using std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two threads (io and otherIo is of boost asio io_context type).

```
  Thread 1 (798c)         |       Thread 2 (681c)
  ----------                      ---------
  io.run()                |       otherIo.run()
```

From first thread i post an event where i make an object named "AnotherA"
and run a function belonging to AnotherA class. AnotherA has a private variable name_
and a function called name() which just prints its name

```
io->post([=]()
    {
        AnotherA aobj(io, otherIo, "Kushina");
        aobj.anotherExecute();
    })
```

anotherExecute() function contains below code:

```
void anotherExecute()
{
    name();
    otherIo_->post(std::bind(&AnotherA::name, this));
}


Output:
--------
2021-05-04 19:08:37 [798c]<info> Constructor called!!!
2021-05-04 19:08:37 [798c]<info> My name is : Kushina,   address: 00FAEB00
2021-05-04 19:08:37 [798c]<info> Destructor called !!!
2021-05-04 19:08:37 [681c]<info> My name is : Kushina,   address: 00FAEB00
```

My question is:

How is the name getting printed second time even after the destructor is called ? If the bind overload i chose makes a copy of AnotherA object (which explains the 2nd print in 1st question) why is the destructor not getting called after the post event finishes running.Also, why is the address of "this" same for both.

name function:

```
void name()
{
    log_info << "My name is : " << name_ << ",   address: " << this;
}
```

Comment: You're using an object that no longer exists and, as the old saying goes, undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I donot understand completely what you mean by "object that no longer exists". Is'nt bind supposed to make a copy of AnotherA object before the destructor gets called in my context?

Comment: No, it copies the pointer you passed to it (`this`). That only one object gets destroyed is a pretty strong hint that only one was created.

Comment: Okie. i get it now thanks @molbdnilo .